# Delete files based on partial names in a text file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to delete all `.mp3` files in `C:\temp` which start with that defined witin a txt file,`Mytxtfile.txt`.

For example, `C:\temp` contains:

```
AliciaEffort.mp3
AliciaKlay.mp3
AliciaLow.mp3
Emanlw.mp3
EmanDown.mp3
JonKLa.mp3
JohnHd.mp3
```

`Mytxtfile.txt` contains:

```
AliciaEffor
Emoanlw
GrezyK
JohnHd
etc.
```

My code:

```
set WORKDIR="C:\temp"
set LISTFILES="C:\Users\StevenRg\Desktop\mytxtfile.txt"
pushd %WORKDIR%
    for %%G in (*) do (
        for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%H in (%LISTFILES%) do (
            if %%G==%%H del /p "%%G"
             )
  )
popd
```

But it doesnt work ...
Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you explain in what way it doesn't work?

Comment: Because on mytxtfile.txt I have defined some word. And I would like to match these word and then delete on the c:\temp every .mp3 that match with the word on the mytxtfile.txt. I should add a regex somewhere ?

Comment: Why didn't you define them one per line in the file? If you did please edit your question to format it accordingly.

Comment: I edit this ^^'

Comment: Convert your textfile into a batchfile, using column mode (Alt+Shift+Arrow in case of Notepad++), this will allow you to put `del ` in front of every line, and `*.mp3` at the end.

Comment: Good idea ! But this is an exemple with mp3.
I have GB of data , how to delete on batch a folder, word that you define on a txt file ? Maybe if I had another IF with regex that match word ...

Comment: Based on your last comment, do you want to delete files which does have a predetermined extension like `.mp3`? or all files which it's base name matches the one in your txtfile. for example if your txtfile contains `abc` then what is your intention? delete  `abc.mp3` or delete `abc.*` ?

Comment: everything that contains the word on the txtfile. For example if on my txtfile I have the word Kiluoa, I want to delete everything who match this word on my C:\temp (which have only mp3 extension)

Comment: Do you want to delete files that *begin with* or *contain* the specific words? Anyway, please put all details from your comments into your question by [edit]ing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do it like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "WorkDir=C:\temp"
Set "ListFile=%UserProfile%\Desktop\mytxtfile.txt"

CD /D "%WorkDir%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
If Not Exist "%ListFile%" Exit /B

For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%ListFile%") Do Del /A /F /Q "%%A*.mp3" 2>Nul
```

Optionally, it may be safer to replace the last line with this:

```bat
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Type "%ListFile%"') Do Del /A /F /Q "%%~A*.mp3" 2>Nul
```

Comment: In what way is the last line safer (besides the disabled `eol`)? are you thinking of character encoding?

Comment: @aschipfl, consider that the text file may not be ASCII text with CRLF line endings.